# Trigger multiple lazy images when modal opens

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, lazy-loading

**Issue**: My code only works with 1 image.
**Goal**: To make it work for multiple images with less code.

I always try to use as less code as possible, avoiding too much javascript or any other language inside the DOM. I have studied some similar questions from the web with no success. I would be grateful if you could assist.

```js
function toggleModal(e, c, t) {
  var d = document.getElementById(c);
  e.checked && d.src != t && (d.src = t)
}
```

```css
.modal-state {
  display: none
}

.modal-state:checked+.modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible
}

.modal-state:checked+.modal .modal__inner {
  top: 0
}

.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  transition: opacity .01s ease;
  z-index: 7;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto
}

.modal__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

.modal__inner {
  transition: top .01s ease;
  height: max-content;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em 1em;
}

.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.1em;
  top: 0;
  /*-.3em*/
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1
}

.modal__close:after,
.modal__close:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: #999;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin: -3px 0 0 -1px;
  top: 0
}

.modal__close:hover:after,
.modal__close:hover:before {
  background: #000
}

.modal__close:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg)
}
```

```html
<p>In our <label for="modal-store">store</label>.</p>

<input class="modal-state" id="modal-store" type="checkbox" onchange="toggleModal(this, 'first-image', 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png')" />

<div class="modal">
  <label class="modal__bg" for="modal-store"></label>
  <div class="modal__inner"><label class="modal__close" for="modal-store"></label>
    <p>
      <div>
        <img id="first-image" src="" loading="lazy">
      </div>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have your array of the images' `id` and image `src`, simply call the `toggleModal` function with the values, iterating through the `cs` parameter which will be the array of id, checking if the input is `checked` and the `src` is not the same with the one in the `ts` array.

There is no need to have the `loading` attribute on the `img` tag set when the `src` of the image is empty, meaning there is nothing to load.

I'll advice you stop using inline event handlers `onevent`.

```js
const c = ['first-image', 'second-image', 'third-image'];
const t = ['https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png', 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png', 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png'];

document.getElementById('modal-store').addEventListener('change', e => toggleModal(e.target, c, t));

function toggleModal(e, cs, ts) {
  cs.forEach((c, i) => {
    var d = document.getElementById(c);
    if (e.checked && d.src != ts[i]) d.src = ts[i];
  });
}
```

```css
.modal-state {
  display: none
}

.modal-state:checked+.modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible
}

.modal-state:checked+.modal .modal__inner {
  top: 0
}

.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  transition: opacity .01s ease;
  z-index: 7;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto
}

.modal__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

.modal__inner {
  transition: top .01s ease;
  height: max-content;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em 1em;
}

.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.1em;
  top: 0;
  /*-.3em*/
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1
}

.modal__close:after,
.modal__close:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: #999;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin: -3px 0 0 -1px;
  top: 0
}

.modal__close:hover:after,
.modal__close:hover:before {
  background: #000
}

.modal__close:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg)
}
```

```html
<p> In our <label for="modal-store">store</label>.</p>
<input class="modal-state" id="modal-store" type="checkbox" />
<div class="modal">
  <label class="modal__bg" for="modal-store"></label>
  <div class="modal__inner">
    <label class="modal__close" for="modal-store"></label>
    <div>
      <div><img id="first-image" /></div>
      <div><img id="second-image" /></div>
      <div><img id="third-image" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I very much appreciate your reply. Please, can you showcase your answer on the snippet?

Comment: Can you give me examples of what the function’s parameters would be like

Comment: 3 images (sources for t parameter): homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png, homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png, homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png. And (c parameter): first, second, third .

Comment: Thank you. This answers the question and will be accepted. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in a second modal, or a third modal, etc. It only works if every modal opens with the specific order in javascript (first-image, second-image, third-image, etc.). It cannot be scaled.

Comment: I don’t understand… what’s your intention with the code

Comment: My initial intention was to apply this javascript in every modal that had images inside them. Can we scale it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232116/discussion-between-a-mola-and-nickdimou).